# Firebase - need to fix javascript sdk auth error

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm always getting this error:

TypeError: firebase.auth is not a function

Here is my code base, can some one help me plz?

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
var firebase = require("firebase/app");    

var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyCGLNi4KMtUSC3CC3s6V-ZLQA87fDEuP-w",
  authDomain: "octatradesfirebasedemo.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://octatradesfirebasedemo.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "octatradesfirebasedemo",
  storageBucket: "octatradesfirebasedemo.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "889486380424",
  appID: "1:889486380424:ios:fb54696dc8f4a731df7e3d"
};

firebase.initializeApp({firebaseConfig});     
 console.log(firebase.auth);    
});
```

Comment: I want to access firebase.auth() method.

what module would require to add for this?

var firebase = require("firebase/app");
 or 
var firebase = require("firebase/auth");

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Firebase Authentication, you'll need to include `firebase/app` and `firebas/auth`.

```
var firebase = require("firebase/app");    
require("firebase/auth");
```

That second require statement will add the `firebase.auth()` object.

Also see the [Add Firebase SDKs and initialize Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add-sdks-initialize) section of the Firebase documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to add  `<script src="/__/firebase/6.6.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>` or `<script defer src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.6.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>` to your app

Comment: Add any one of them to your `<head>` or `<body>` tags